# How to reshape tabular data to one row per group

Tags: r, reshape

I am an R (and coding novice) and I am looking for a way to reconfigure Table A show below into Table B.

Table A:

```
type   x1  x2  x3  
A      4   6   9  
A      7   4   1  
A      9   6   2   
B      1   3   8  
B      2   7   9
```

I am looking for code that would convert to the following

Table B:

```
type   x1  x2  x3  x1'  x2'  x3'  x1'' x2'' x3''  
A      4    6   9   7    4   1    9     6   2  
B      1    3   8   2    7   9
```

The real Table A is over 150000 rows and 36 Columns. With 2100 unique "type" values.

Thanks for the help.

-Shawn

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I notice that Vector B is multidimensional, so it's what we'd call a data.frame or matrix in R parlance. Is that what you mean? Or did you want 3 separate vectors?

Comment: We can call Vector B a Matrix as well.  I edited the original questions to make it more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. I made an ad hoc solution then we got attacked by the downvote-with-no-comment troll monster, so I had to delete it. If your data is large or if you need to do this a lot we should find a more programmatic solution anyway. The only real difficulty is that in this format we need to add NA's for the missing cells of B. So I'm thinking that utilizing `fill = T` with a `for` loop, `cbind` and `rbind` is a way to go.

Comment: The real Table A is over 150000 rows and 36 Columns.  With 2100 unique "type" values.

Comment: @Hack-R it was not a monster, I dv'd because it was a literal extraction of the example and had no application for any real data. The answer, as is, is unhelpful to the community. Please feel free to improve the post.

Comment: @PierreLafortune If you don't leave a comment, you're still a monster (no offense; I'm in the large minority of users who say downvoting without commenting should be disallowed). Like I was saying in that answer it wasn't a *good* solution as-is but a solution that could be made programmatic if you understand how a `for` loop works. When there's no other solution I'd say that ones as such can be very useful. They've saved me a number of times. Anyway, at least you left a comment now, which I do applaud :)

Comment: @Hack-R An explanation is unnecessary for a very low quality answer. I will judge for myself when it is required. Your answer provided zero help to the OP or community. Reopen if you disagree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, this solution seems pretty straightforward

```
# split the data frame by type and use unlist, which will provide names
ld <- lapply(split(d[-1], d[["type"]]), unlist)

# gather all the unique names in the list
ldNames <- Reduce(unique, lapply(ld, names))

# use the names to index each list element, which makes them
# all of equal length and suitable for row binding.  
do.call(rbind, lapply(ld, function(x) x[ldNames]))
#   x11 x12 x13 x21 x22 x23 x31 x32 x33
# A   4   7   9   6   4   6   9   1   2
# B   1   2  NA   3   7  NA   8   9  NA
```

If the order of the output above is not satisfactory, you can rearrange:

```
# save the output from above
d2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(ld, function(x) x[ldNames]))
# reorder the names
ldNames_sorted <- c(matrix(ldNames, ncol = (ncol(d) - 1), byrow = TRUE))

# apply the new order.
d2 <- d2[, ldNames_sorted]
#  x11 x21 x31 x12 x22 x32 x13 x23 x33
#A   4   6   9   7   4   1   9   6   2
#B   1   3   8   2   7   9  NA  NA  NA
```

To add a column for type instead of using row names, one method would be:

```
data.frame(type = row.names(d2), d2)
```

Comment: Relly like the method combining `lapply` and `split`. Great! (+1). However, the final output of B doesn't match the question, you can update the solution ;)

Comment: One last questions.  We need the column with the "type" to have a column heading.

Comment: @SDM1212 I added a final line at the end to add a `type` column.  Hope that helps!

Comment: @Jota - Perfect! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but this can also be done quite easily with the `dcast` function of the `data.table` package because you can use multiple `value.var`'s in it:

```
library(data.table)

dcast(setDT(d), type ~ rowid(type), value.var = c('x1','x2','x3'), sep = '')
```

which gives:

> ```
>    type x11 x12 x13 x21 x22 x23 x31 x32 x33
> 1:    A   4   7   9   6   4   6   9   1   2
> 2:    B   1   2  NA   3   7  NA   8   9  NA
> ```

---

You can also do this in base R with:

```
d$num <- ave(d$x1, d$type, FUN = seq_along)
reshape(d, idvar = 'type', direction = 'wide', timevar = 'num', sep = '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a try and the solution is not such concise, just give you a hint.I think lots of things can be improved.

But finally we have to introduce NAs in here :(

```
zz <- "type   x1  x2  x3  
A      4   6   9  
A      7   4   1  
A      9   6   2   
B      1   3   8  
B      2   7   9"

dA <- read.table(text=zz, header=T)


tmp<-(sapply(unique(dA$type), FUN=function(x) as.vector(t(dA[dA$type == x, -1]))))

t(sapply(tmp, '[', seq(max(sapply(tmp, length)))))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    4    6    9    7    4    1    9    6    2
[2,]    1    3    8    2    7    9   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a <- data.frame(type=c("A", "A","A", "B", "B"), x1 = c(4,7,9,1,2),x2=c(6,4,6,3,7),
               x3 = c(9,1,2,8,9))

library(dplyr)
tmp <-
a %>% 
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarise(no_rows = length(type))

for(i in unique(a$type)){
  n <- max(tmp$no_rows) - nrow(a[a$type == i,])
  nn <- nrow(a)
  if(n > 0){
    for(ii in 1:n){
      a[nn+ii,] <- c(i,NA,NA,NA)
    }    
  }

}

a <- a[order(a$type),]
a$timevar <- seq(1:max(tmp$no_rows) )

b<-reshape(a,timevar="timevar",idvar="type",direction="wide",drop = F)
b

  type x1.1 x2.1 x3.1 x1.2 x2.2 x3.2 x1.3 x2.3 x3.3
1    A    4    6    9    7    4    1    9    6    2
4    B    1    3    8    2    7    9 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: I think your logic is sound, but it can be simplified a fair bit. See my answer which I think does the same thing (I think - this is a deceptively difficult question)

Comment: @thelatemail I have no doubt you're right. I'll +1 your answer

Answer (score 1):

Variation on @Hack-R's answer:

```
A$num <- with(A, ave(as.character(type), type, FUN=seq_along) )
tmp <- cbind(A[c(1,5)], stack(A[2:4]))
tmp$time <- paste(tmp$ind, tmp$num, sep=".")

reshape(tmp[c("type","time","values")], idvar="type", timevar="time", direction="wide")

#  type values.x1.1 values.x1.2 values.x1.3 values.x2.1 values.x2.2 values.x2.3 values.x3.1 values.x3.2 values.x3.3
#1    A           4           7           9           6           4           6           9           1           2
#4    B           1           2          NA           3           7          NA           8           9          NA
```

And a dplyr version for fun:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

A %>%
  gather(var, value, -type) %>%
  group_by(type,var) %>%
  mutate(time=seq_along(var)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  unite(grpvar, c(time,var) ) %>%
  spread(grpvar, value )

#Source: local data frame [2 x 10]
#
#   type  1_x1  1_x2  1_x3  2_x1  2_x2  2_x3  3_x1  3_x2  3_x3
#  (chr) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int)
#1     A     4     6     9     7     4     1     9     6     2
#2     B     1     3     8     2     7     9    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: Hi - I am not sure how to use this with @Hack-R's answer.

Comment: @SDM1212 - it's a complete answer in its own right based on Hack-R's logic. You don't have to use it with anything else.

Comment: OK I am starting to understand and I got the example to run. So for the real data the number of obs. will change but there will always be 22 variables.  I am not sure how to change this example to work with my real data.